# Using fgets to store character pointer program crashes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, fgets

```
char *p;
fgets(p,10,stdin);
```

Why is this crashing my program? Seems like I can't use char pointers in Fgets but I can use arrays so it makes no sense.

Comment: char pointers are not arrays.

Comment: To start with, they have to point to something valid before you dereference them, eg. try to write through them.

Comment: Really? Guess my understanding is weak then. I read that arrays are just pointers.

Comment: If you read that on a site, delete the bookmark and/or history.  If it's in a paper book, apply gasoline and a match.

Comment: @MartinJames we don't need anymore global warming. A shredder will do just fine. :P

Comment: Hah. Probably my mistake for misunderstanding what they said. So from what you said, can I say pointers may not have memory allocated to them while array always do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Seems like I can't use char pointers in Fgets but I can use arrays*

No, you can use both, as long as you allocate memory to the pointer before passing that to `fgets()`.

In this case, using pointers,

```
 char *p;
```

`p` is unitialized and points to some arbitrary memory location which is invalid. You need to allocate proper memory to `p` before you can read/write something to/from the memory location pointer by `p`.

Comment: How do I know how much memory I give to p if I don't know the input length from the user?

Comment: @qaispak You must be knowing the length, otherwise how do you suggest the _array_ worked?

Comment: Sorry, by that I actually meant: "The array (when I know the length), I can get input but I want to know how to get it if I don't know the length... which I assumed is when we use pointers (but I am wrong since we need to define length for pointers as well)

Comment: @qaispak yes, `fgets()` wont allocate memory to the pointer. You need to allocate memory prior to passing the pointer.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how do I know how much memory to allocate?

Comment: @qaispak you don't. Usually we do it the other way. allocate memory first, and then restrict the user input using the size supplied with `fgets()`.

Comment: If you are handling text lines, go with 256 - it's a nice, shiny number.